# Creating a new project and bundle - "Did you forget a 'use' statement for another namespace?"

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to create a test project with a test bundle. I get the below error:

> Attempted to load class "TestBundle" from namespace "test". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

I have read all the instructions on the Symfony website and tried many different things but no joy.

**test/config/bundles.php**

```php
    return [
        Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
        test\TestBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    ];
```

**test/src/TestBundle/TestBundle.php**

```php
namespace test\TestBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class TestBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getPath(): string
    {
        return \dirname(__DIR__);
    }
}
```

**test/src/TestBundle/composer.json**

```json
{
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "name": "TestBundle",
    "type": "testing building a reusuable bundle",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/console": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.4.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "test\\TestBundle\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "test\\TestBundle\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

**test/composer.json**

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/console": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "5.4.*",   
    "test/TestBundle": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I havent got that far yet, there are no dependancies, its basically an empty bundle at the moment so it shouldnt need composer to install it surely?

Comment: Following the instructions I thought the bundles.php did this?

Comment: No, it's unrelated. How could `bundles.php` tell the autoloader anything, while the file has no knowledge of where the referred classes are defined.

Comment: Ahh its the composer.json file?  I forgot to add that to the post, I will add it now.

Comment: Please share more details. As far as I see, you don't have any class called  `test\TestBundle`, but one that is called `test\TestBundle\TestBundle` - have you tried using that in `bundles.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not installing the "bundle" using composer, the autoloader does not get generated, and the class pertaining to your new package will never be found.

The bundle's `composer.json` file is irrelevant, since again, you are not installing the package through composer. Thus, it's never read.

But you can instruct composer to generate autoloader files that take this new bundle into account.

Let's say that this is your directory structure:

```
- config     <--- where bundles.php resides, among other files
- src        <--- the application code that "consumes" your bundle,  
- testBundle <--- This is where you have your bundle's code. 
- vendor     
- etc
```

Note that your bundle's code **is not on the same directory than the rest of the application code**.

Now in your **application** `composer.json` file you should need to add something like:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": 
            {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "test\\TestBundle\\": "testBundle/"
        }
    }
}
```

After doing this, you should re-dump the autoloader (`composer dump-autoload`) and the files should be discoverable.

(Note, in your question, you say that the namespace for `TestBundle` is `test\TestBundle`, but then in `bundles.php` you try to use `test\TestBundle::class`. One of those things is wrong, it's either `namespace test;`, or `test\TestBundle\TestBundle::class`).

Comment: @LeeTee Here is a simple working [example](https://github.com/cerad/s52bundle).